# animation with using gsap

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

There is such an animation, now when the site header touches the elements 01/08 02/08 03/08 04/08 05/08 06/08 07/08 08/08 we have one element painted over. But I need to make sure that when the logo is in the middle of the screen and at the same level with the text, the same animation occurs.

For example, our logo and text are at the same level in the middle of the screen - the scrolling element is painted over.
instead of painting over the element when we reach 01/08, we will calculate that they are on the same level

```
          <div class="slide group7 slide--autoheight slide-nav" id="services">
            <div class="slide__lines"></div>
            <div class="slide__inner">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="box row scol">
                  <div class="box__left">
                    <div class="text text--main">
                      <h2>IT solutions for your business tasks</h2>
                      <p class="g5">We create IT products, automate workflows and increase their efficiency, integrate advanced IT technologies for the
                        development of your company.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-snow">

                    <div class="text t1">
                      <div class="text__date">01/08</div>
                      <h3>IT consulting</h3>
                      <p class="g5">We analyze your business model, find weaknesses and identify growth points. We assess the readiness of your company to implement information architecture, develop a new business model or suggest how to optimize an existing one. We will show our strategic vision of how to solve business problems in order to ensure its sustainable development by introducing and modernizing the corporate IT infrastructure.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text t2">
                      <div class="text__date">02/08</div>
                      <h3>Custom Software Development Services</h3>
                      <p class="g5">Each company has various needs, so there is no ready-made standard solution that would suit everyone, and it is not desirable to implement something that does not fully solve the set tasks. We will develop a software product for the tasks of your business. We create an IT solution for unlimited scalability of your company, automation of routine processes and recurring tasks. We increase the efficiency of your employees so that you can use your human resources to achieve larger goals.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text t3">
                      <div class="text__date">03/08</div>
                      <h3>Enterprise Web Design and Development</h3>
                      <p class="g5">We develop multi-aspect web services, integrate them into company's IT architecture so that they form a single system and automate business workflow. We create corporate services, personal accounts, management systems with compound features, but a simple and convenient interface, to make web services work for people, increasing productivity, expanding business opportunities, assisting a company to grow and increase its profits.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="text t4">
                      <div class="text__date">04/08</div>
                      <h3>React, Flutter, Ionic, and Native App Development</h3>
                      <p class="g5">GartLight develops cross-platform mobile applications using React, Flutter, Ionic frameworks. A feature of our products is high performance, speed, reliability, and ability to integrate with other corporate services. Take your business to a new digital level; optimize the company's internal tasks, speed up communication, increase customer loyalty and engagement.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text t5">
                      <div class="text__date">05/08</div>
                      <h3>Data Science, Machine Learning, and Artificial Intelligence</h3>
                      <p class="g5">Make management decisions based on figures and reliable data. We develop a platform comprising statistics and analytics. Our experts will assist to improve business processes and open up new opportunities for your company – to increase the speed of data collection, the accuracy of analysis by introducing intelligent algorithms into the infrastructure. An IT system will reduce manual operation, the number of errors and save time for employees.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="text t6">
                      <div class="text__date">06/08</div>
                      <h3>Cloud Integration and API Development</h3>
                      <p class="g5">Make your business safer, more efficient and more profitable with our certified experts who can help you to develop and implement the best IT cloud integration strategy. We will assist you to avoid data dispersion, increase the flexibility and performance of your company, improve the real-time operation of employees, and make updates using intelligent applications. We provide round-the-clock access to information and cyber security.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="text t7">
                      <div class="text__date">07/08</div>
                      <h3>Identity Management</h3>
                      <p class="g5">In large companies whose information infrastructure is used not only by employees, but also by suppliers, partners, customers, it is difficult to effectively manage user accounts and access permissions. We automate identity management, including the full life cycle of employee accounts, information asset and access rights management processes. We eliminate multiple authentication, improve user experience. We improve the security and efficiency of information systems, reduce the administration time and costs, and reduce the number of recurring tasks.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="text t8">
                      <div class="text__date">08/08</div>
                      <h3>Cybersecurity</h3>
                      <p class="g5">We develop an information security system that is protected from any threats and meets international standards. We evaluate its resistance to internal and external threats, eliminate any vulnerabilities. We perform a risk assessment to determine the key targets for possible attacks. We protect your customers, partners, employees and corporate data from cybercriminals. Today, business viability depends on how properly your data is protected. By investing in information security, you reduce risks.</p>
                      <a href="#contacts" class="btn btn--link">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="box__right a-logo">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 275 275" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                      <path
                        d="M209.136 196.511L196.146 209.5C196.044 209.602 195.867 209.602 195.74 209.5L124.906 138.666C124.652 138.413 124.5 138.057 124.5 137.702H151.266C151.266 138.057 151.418 138.413 151.697 138.666L209.161 196.13C209.237 196.232 209.237 196.409 209.136 196.511Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l6" fill="url(#c)" />
                      <path
                        d="M229.559 128.214H172.475C171.714 128.214 171.004 128.518 170.446 129.051L162.809 136.687C162.53 136.966 162.378 137.322 162.403 137.677C162.403 138.032 162.53 138.387 162.809 138.666L170.446 146.303C170.979 146.835 171.714 147.14 172.475 147.14H229.584C229.686 147.14 229.736 147.064 229.736 146.988V128.366C229.736 128.29 229.66 128.214 229.559 128.214Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l7" fill="url(#b)" />
                      <path
                        d="M209.136 79.1726L160.145 128.188L151.672 136.636C151.393 136.916 151.24 137.296 151.266 137.677H124.475C124.449 137.296 124.602 136.916 124.881 136.636L195.74 65.777C195.842 65.6756 196.019 65.6756 196.146 65.777L209.136 78.7667C209.262 78.8935 209.262 79.0711 209.136 79.1726Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l8" fill="url(#a)" />
                      <path
                        d="M146.75 173.373V229.822C146.75 229.974 146.623 230.101 146.471 230.101H128.103C128.026 230.101 127.95 230.076 127.9 230C127.849 229.949 127.823 229.873 127.823 229.797L127.9 153.305L145.913 171.318C146.445 171.876 146.75 172.612 146.75 173.373Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l5" />
                      <path
                        d="M127.9 153.33V160.586L78.8078 209.526C78.7064 209.627 78.5288 209.627 78.4019 209.526L65.4123 196.536C65.3108 196.434 65.3108 196.257 65.4123 196.13L114.453 147.089H121.684L127.9 153.33Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l4" />
                      <path
                        d="M113.312 138.717L121.684 147.089H114.453L45.1414 147.115C45.0906 147.115 45.0653 147.115 45.0399 147.089C44.9384 147.038 44.8623 146.937 44.8623 146.835V128.467C44.8623 128.315 44.9892 128.188 45.1414 128.188H114.402H121.836L113.286 136.738C112.753 137.271 112.753 138.184 113.312 138.717Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l3" />
                      <path
                        d="M127.9 114.793V122.125L121.836 128.188H114.402L65.4123 79.1726C65.3108 79.0711 65.3108 78.8935 65.4123 78.7667L78.4273 65.777C78.5288 65.6756 78.7064 65.6756 78.8332 65.777L127.9 114.793Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l2" />
                      <path
                        d="M146.75 45.5061V102.082C146.75 102.843 146.445 103.579 145.913 104.112L127.9 122.125L127.849 45.5061C127.849 45.4554 127.874 45.3793 127.9 45.3285C127.95 45.2524 128.026 45.227 128.103 45.2017H146.471C146.623 45.2017 146.75 45.3285 146.75 45.5061Z"
                        stroke="#C1C1C1" stroke-width="0.439855" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="l-fill l1" /><defs>
                          <linearGradient display="none" id="a" x1="127.058" y1="172.858" x2="209.896" y2="171.118" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                            <stop stop-color="#3DC7C7" />
                            <stop offset=".14" stop-color="#3CC3C7" />
                            <stop offset=".29" stop-color="#39B6C6" />
                            <stop offset=".45" stop-color="#34A1C4" />
                            <stop offset=".6" stop-color="#2E83C2" />
                            <stop offset=".76" stop-color="#255DBF" />
                            <stop offset=".92" stop-color="#1B2FBC" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1515BA" />
                          </linearGradient>
                          <linearGradient display="none" id="b" x1="164.376" y1="136.991" x2="229.984" y2="132.832" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                            <stop stop-color="#3DC7C7" />
                            <stop offset=".14" stop-color="#3CC3C7" />
                            <stop offset=".29" stop-color="#39B6C6" />
                            <stop offset=".45" stop-color="#34A1C4" />
                            <stop offset=".6" stop-color="#2E83C2" />
                            <stop offset=".76" stop-color="#255DBF" />
                            <stop offset=".92" stop-color="#1B2FBC" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1515BA" />
                          </linearGradient>
                          <linearGradient display="none" id="c" x1="127.032" y1="100.907" x2="209.912" y2="99.168" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                            <stop stop-color="#3DC7C7" />
                            <stop offset=".14" stop-color="#3CC3C7" />
                            <stop offset=".29" stop-color="#39B6C6" />
                            <stop offset=".45" stop-color="#34A1C4" />
                            <stop offset=".6" stop-color="#2E83C2" />
                            <stop offset=".76" stop-color="#255DBF" />
                            <stop offset=".92" stop-color="#1B2FBC" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#1515BA" />
                          </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide group7 slide--autoheight">
            <div class="slide__lines"></div>
            <div class="slide__inner nopad">
              <div class="container col">
                <div class="box row mcol">
                  <div class="box__left">
                    <h2>Some of <span class="gradient">Our Valued Customers</span></h2>
                    <ul class="our-clients-img">
                      <li><img src="images/logo-theworldbank.svg" alt="The World Bank"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/logo-hbo.svg" alt="HBO"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/logo-nbc.svg" alt="NBC"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/logo-deutschebank.svg" alt="Deutsche Bank"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/logo-moodys.svg" alt="Moody's"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/logo-bankofamerica.svg" alt="Bank of America"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/logo-citi.svg" alt="Citi"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/logo-aon.svg" alt="Aon"></li>
                      <li><img src="images/discovery.svg" alt="Discovery"></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="box__right iso">
                    <div class="text text--main">
                      <h2><span class="gradient">Our expertise</span> is confirmed by international ISO certification</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                      <img src="images/iso27001.png" alt="">
                      <p>ISO 27001 certificate officially confirms Gartlight's systematic approach to managing people, processes and IT systems by applying the secure risk management procedures.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                      <img src="images/iso9001.png" alt="">
                      <p>ISO 9001 certificate proves that Gartlight creates all solutions considering international quality and safety standards.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

```
gsap.to(".a-logo", {
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".a-logo",
        marginTop: 120,
        start: "top top",
        end: () => `+=${document.querySelector(".a-logo").offsetHeight - 300}`,
        pin: true,
    }
});

const services = gsap.utils.toArray('.text-snow .text');

services.forEach((service, index) => {
    gsap.from(service, {
        scrollTrigger: {
            start: '-100px',
            end: 'top',
            trigger: service,
            scrub: true,
            onEnter: function () {
                document.querySelector('.a-logo').classList.add('l' + `${index + 1}`);
            },
            onEnterBack: function () {
                document.querySelector('.a-logo').classList.remove('l' + `${index + 1}`);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I tried different methods, but I just can’t figure out how to implement exactly the option I need.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.